# Replace Smary variable syntax

Tags: string, variables, replace, smarty

I want to modify a string with replace in Smarty.

```
{$var|replace:'aaa':'bbb'}
```

Simple. But I need to replace this:

```
{$var|replace:'value="AA"':'value="$string_b"'}
```

I've also tried with the following syntax with no success:

```
{$var|replace:'value="AA"':'value="'$string_b'"'}
{$var|replace:'value="AA"':'value="`$string_b`"'}
{$var|replace:'value="AA"':'value=""$string_b""'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclose the string in double quotes if you want smarty to recognize variables inside, so in your case you also have to escape the double quotes inside the string:

```
{$var|replace:'value="AA"':"value=\"{$string_b}\""}
```

Using brackets around the variable is not necessary but recommended

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to find the right syntax to use.

```
{$var|replace:"value=\"AA\"":"value=\"$string\"}
```